# How can I access location information via rules, to include the City of a node in an email?

Tags: rules, location

I have a rule, which works like this:
After saving new content, Fetch users who have flagged a Taxonomy term, Loop, send email.
The emails get sent perfectly, to users who have flagged the specific term.

Now I would like to include the location, from the new content item which is saved, in the email.

If I look for the relevant Replacement Patterns [node:location] is available, but does not print anything when included in the email. I'm guessing this is because [node:location] is an array and I need to do something else to explode the array to get "City" out and print it in the email...

Does anyone know how I would do that? Or a better way to access the specifics (i.e. City) from a node location?

NB: The Location information for my content type is NOT added as "fields" but is added to the content type under "Locative information" (next to Comment Settings and Menu Settings in D7) I am only collecting City and Postcode (and forcing Country to the default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Location module defines tokens for each piece of info (see below from location.tokens.inc)

So based on this, [node:location:city] should work for a single value, or [node:location:city:0] for the first value if there were multiple values.

```
  $location['name'] = array(
    'name' => t("Location Name"),
    'description' => t('Location Name (If there are multiple locations, N is the iteration, starting with 0).'),
    'dynamic' => TRUE,
  );
  $location['street'] = array(
    'name' => t("Street"),
    'description' => t("Street (If there are multiple locations, N is the iteration, starting with 0)."),
    'dynamic' => TRUE,
  );
  $location['additional'] = array(
    'name' => t("Additional"),
    'description' => t("Additional (If there are multiple locations, N is the iteration, starting with 0)."),
    'dynamic' => TRUE,
  );
  $location['city'] = array(
    'name' => t("City"),
    'description' => t("City (If there are multiple locations, N is the iteration, starting with 0)."),
    'dynamic' => TRUE,
  );
  $location['province'] = array(
    'name' => t("State/Province"),
    'description' => t("State/Province (If there are multiple locations, N is the iteration, starting with 0)."),
    'dynamic' => TRUE,
  );
  $location['province_name'] = array(
    'name' => t("State/Province Name"),
    'description' => t("State/Province Name (If there are multiple locations, N is the iteration, starting with 0)."),
    'dynamic' => TRUE,
  );
  $location['postal_code'] = array(
    'name' => t("Postal Code"),
    'description' => t("Postal Code (If there are multiple locations, N is the iteration, starting with 0)."),
    'dynamic' => TRUE,
  );
  $location['latitude'] = array(
    'name' => t("Latitude"),
    'description' => t("Latitude (If there are multiple locations, N is the iteration, starting with 0)."),
    'dynamic' => TRUE,
  );
  $location['longitude'] = array(
    'name' => t("Longitude"),
    'description' => t("Longitude (If there are multiple locations, N is the iteration, starting with 0)."),
    'dynamic' => TRUE,
  );
  $location['country'] = array(
    'name' => t("Country"),
    'description' => t("Country (If there are multiple locations, N is the iteration, starting with 0)."),
    'dynamic' => TRUE,
  );
  $location['country_name'] = array(
    'name' => t("Country Name"),
    'description' => t("Country Name (If there are multiple locations, N is the iteration, starting with 0)."),
    'dynamic' => TRUE,
  );
```

Comment: [node:location:city] worked for me, Thanks thumbson